# Editing the content from the page using Content Query web part

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, content-query-web-part

Can you edit the content in a content query web part?  Or any items edited, added or delete is done at the source of the content query only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either content query or content search web part, the original data is maintained through the data source, so we can not change the data from the web part itself.

If you are using the SharePoint 2013 version you may use the content search web part than the content query web part which has performance issue.

Comment: That's what I thought...and it makes sense.  You wouldn't want someone from the Sub-Site making changes to the main list.